# How to run 2 modules in one file in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a report in VBA that allows to insert a folder directory into cell “C7”.
Then Moduole1 will return hyperlink to all the files that are in a folder (“C7”), all the file names, files dimension and a date of the last modification.
Module1 script is:

```
Dim iRow
Sub IndiceFile()
If Range("C7").Value = "" Then
 MsgBox "Insert the path into C7"

 Range("B11:E1048576").Select
 Selection.ClearContents

 Range("C7").Select
 Else
Range("B11:E1048576").Select
Selection.ClearContents
    iRow = 11
    Call ListMyFiles(Range("C7"), Range("C8"))
    MsgBox "Path is detected"
    End If

    End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath, IncludeSubfolders)
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each myFile In mySource.Files
        iCol = 2
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Name
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)
        Next
    End If

    Range("B11:B1048576").Select

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If Cell <> "" Then
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cell, Cell.Value
            Range("C10").Select
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

The second Module will add another column to a report with a count of rows in each file.

```
Option Explicit
    Sub CountRows()
        Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
        Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
        Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
        Dim lngNextRow As Long, lngRowCount As Long
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '   Open a current workbook with one worksheet to list the results
        Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
        Set wsDest = wbDest.ActiveSheet
    '   Set the location of the folder for the source files
        strFolder = Range("C7").Value 
    '   Call the first file from the folder
        strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.*")
    '   Loop through each file in the folder
    '   Return the count of rows for each file in the destination file
        lngNextRow = 11
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFolder & strFile)
            Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
            lngRowCount = wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    '       wsDest.Cells(lngNextRow, "A").Value = strFile
            wsDest.Cells(lngNextRow, "F").Value = lngRowCount
            wbSource.Close savechanges:=False
            lngNextRow = lngNextRow + 1
    '       Call the next file from the folder
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

The goal is to create a Module3 that will run first Module1 then Module2.
The problem is that separately (in 2 different files) both modules work. But when I try to lunch Module1 and then Module2 (even manually) the Module2 does not return any result anymore.

Maybe someone can help to understand a reason of this problem?

Comment: If you want you could email your files and I will take a look at them

Comment: Thank you! If You have some time to take a look, i will send you an example.

Comment: @VBAProgrammer: why not just provide an answer based on code?

Comment: Sometimes its hard to understand the question without all the files Philip. But I will be sure to update the answer here once we figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CountRows()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim lngNextRow As Long, lngRowCount As Long
    Dim MyObject As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim mySource As Folder
    Dim myFile As Scripting.File
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'   Open a current workbook with one worksheet to list the results
    Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wbDest.ActiveSheet
'   Set the location of the folder for the source files
    strFolder = Range("C7").Value
'   Call the first file from the folder
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(strFolder)

'   Loop through each file in the folder
'   Return the count of rows for each file in the destination file
    lngNextRow = 11
    For Each myFile In mySource.Files

        strPath = myFile.Path
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
        lngRowCount = wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'       wsDest.Cells(lngNextRow, "A").Value = strFile
        wsDest.Cells(lngNextRow, "F").Value = lngRowCount
        wbSource.Close savechanges:=False
        lngNextRow = lngNextRow + 1
'       Call the next file from the folder

   Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I think there was also mistake in a Module 3 that lunches Module1 and Module2.

Comment: glad I could help. Also I've edited the main post and kept just the relevant parts to make it easier for others to understand the question